# Make button visible at the start of every hour?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My main activity has a button that opens a form activity where you submit data. After submitting data the Button will disappear. How do I make it appear at the start of every hour in the day?

For example, if I submitted data at 7:05pm, the button would disappear until 8:00pm. When I press the button to submit data again, the button would disappear until 9:00pm, and so on.

Comment: try jobScheduler or AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

When you submit data get current timestamp and store it in sharedPref.When you start activity check the sharedPref and compare it with the current time of device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the background service and set the notify interval at 1 hours and 
start the service when button click and after than whatever you want to do with this background service

```
BackgroundService.java

public class BackgroundService extends Service {

public static final int notify = 100000;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 1 Minute)

private Timer mTimer = null;    //timer handling

Context context;

ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor;

View view;

Handler mHandler = new Handler();

/** indicates how to behave if the service is killed */
int mStartMode;

/** interface for clients that bind */
IBinder mBinder;

/** indicates whether onRebind should be used */
boolean mAllowRebind;

/** Called when the service is being created. */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (mTimer != null) // Cancel if already existed
        mTimer.cancel();
    else
        mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);   //Schedule task
}

/** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
    return null;
}

/** Called when all clients have unbound with unbindService() */
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return mAllowRebind;
}

/** Called when a client is binding to the service with bindService()*/
@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {

}

/** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mTimer.cancel();    //For Cancel Timer
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//class TimeDisplay for handling task
class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Service Start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<service android:name=".BackgroundService.KametSportsEventsService" android:enabled="true" />
```

//Start background service

startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundService.class));

//Stop Background Service

stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundService.class));